# canjs mustache templates showing __!!__ __!!__ in the output

Tags: mustache, canjs

canjs mustache templates showing **!!** **!!** in the output. I just don't understand where it is coming from. I tried using the following code in mustache template. It shows **!!** **!!** above the table header and not showing anything in tbody. If I use #each **!!** is being displayed in each of the tds

```
<tbody>
        {{#tableData}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{group}}</td>
                    <td>{{product}}</td>
                    <td>{{service}}</td>
                    <td>{{country}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="delete-project"
                                        can-click="deleteService" title="Delete"></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {{/tableData}} 
                {{^tableData}}
                <tr>
                <td colspan='13' class="emptyTableMessage">No Data</td>
                </tr>
            {{/tableData}}
</tbody>
```

Comment: This happens because can.view.hookup is not called.  How are you rendering this template?

Comment: can.append(can.$('main'), can.view('<path to mustache template>')({}));

Comment: Try `can.append(can.$('main'), can.view.frag(can.view('<path to mustache template>')({})), can.$('main')); `